# Break (C-c C-c) in ESS-remote R shell

Tags: shell, ess

I am running my R scripts on a remote shell using

```
M-x shell
ssh -X -C name@server.edu
srun -p nodeX --pty R  (slurm command to start R)
M-x ess-remote and select 'R'
```

everythink works fine, until I want to break (usually `C-c C-c` within shell). Breaking also does not work using the menu bar. It keeps running.
Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: the recommended way to use ess on a remote machine is via tramp: http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-processes-on-Remote-Computers . That might work better than ess-remote

Answer (score 1):

Here is an intermediate work-around for my problem.
In R, to omit accidentally printing long outputs, one can set

```
options(max.print=999)
```

e.g., to limit the maximum number of printed lines to 999 (helpful for large datasets). Still not the perfect solution, but it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can interrupt the remote process with `C-q C-c<RET>` in the shell buffer.

`C-q` inserts the following key into the shell ( in this case `C-c` : a break).

Comment: It inserts a `^C` into the shell, but the output keeps going. Simply tried it with `c(1:10000) RET C-q C-c RET`. It keeps scrolling.